# How can I validate an xml having duplicate child element as tags unique by Id?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I have an xml in below format :

```
<data>
   <index id="Name">Mesut</index>
   <index id="Age">28</index>
</data>
```

now this xml's element are same which is index. XSD generated from this is as below :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="data">
          <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="index" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string">
                               <xs:complexType>
                                      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>                                                            
                                </xs:complexType>                   
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The problem with above xsd is that This xsd can not validate an xml having same tag as index which comes there 2 times one time in form of String and second time in form of Integer. Because the xsd can only validate the string.

Now the Code i'm using to validate is as below :

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean b = true;
    File fXml = new File("C:\\Users\\Mesut\\Desktop\\XMLAndXSD\\MainXml.xml");
    File fXsd = new File("C:\\Users\\Mesut\\Desktop\\XMLAndXSD\\MainXml.xsd");
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    try {           
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(fXsd);
        schema.newValidator().validate(new StreamSource(fXml));
    } catch(SAXException sax) {         
        System.out.println("exception in sax");
        b = false;
        sax.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException io) {
        System.out.println("exception in io");
        b = false;
        io.printStackTrace();
    }       
    System.out.println(b);}
```

And the exception on running above code is as below :

```
enter code hereorg.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Vikas/Desktop/XMLAndXSD/MainXml.xsd; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 93; src-element.3: Element 'index' has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is allowed for an element.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
```

Comment: Your schema is not valid in it's current form. You cannot define an attribute at the level you have done.

Comment: @Tom Redfern. I generated this xsd from 1+ of online websites. Everywhere the xsd got generated was same. Can you help me out to get the correct ones. Please..

Answer (score 1):

Use the [extension](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_extension.asp) tag to create a new type which extends xs:string to include the attribute id. At the start of the schema place:

```
<xs:complexType name="indexType">
   <xs:simpleContent>
     <xs:extension base="xs:string">
       <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
     </xs:extension>
   </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Then in "data" do:

```
<xs:element name="index" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="indexType"/>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this ?

Comment: Umm, I can try but it's pretty much all there. The extension tag allows you to define a new type based on an existing schema type (in this case xs:string). My example creates the type "indexType" which then can be used as the type for the "index" element tag

Comment: If you want more info, please follow the link in my answer to the W3Schools webpage. It's a good resource for common mark-up languages

Answer (score 0):

Building on @mascoj's answer, try this schema:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://myns">
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="index" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" use="optional"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

That validates the following xml instance:

```
<f:data xmlns:f="http://myns">
   <f:index id="Name">Mesut</f:index>
   <f:index id="Age">28</f:index>
</f:data>
```